# angular cli : ng commands shows Invalid character error

Tags: angular-cli

I tried to find the version of angular cli after successful installation but it shows a **Window Script Host** model pop up with an error.

Installation:
[image]

Windows Script Host appears after I tried with

```
ng version
```

Answer (score 7):

Remove this path in environment variables

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin
```

Then add this path to environment variables if you have not already

```
 C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this same issue, I had to delete the ***system*** environment variable for the Angular CLI and then restart my console window.

`C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin`

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error and wanted to share some insights on how I resolved it.

### Error Details-

### (my username)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng.js
Line: 1 Character: 1
Error: Invalid Character
Code: 800A03F6
Source: Compilation error Microsoft Jscript

Probable Cause-

> When you try to install @angular/cli globally, there seems to be an issue with the build in ng.js file.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Resolution-

> Uninstall the globally installed angular/cli

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

> Clear npm Cache -

```
npm cache clean --force
```

> Install @angular/cli locally and it seems to be working fine.

```
npm install @angular/cli
```

> Also, after installation make sure you add the path to your environment variable

Example- "C:\Users{user_name}\node_modules.bin

It will be installed in the path where you'll run the installation for angular/cli

Answer (score -1):

Remove the user environment variable

```
C:\Users\satsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin
```

Comment: same issue, again

Comment: have you reopened the command prompt?